# The console is supposed to throw exception if I enter a negative number but it is not working. Am I missing something here?

Tags: c#, if-statement, exception, throw

```
public decimal CurrentBalance = 1000.00m;
public decimal WithdrawCurrentAmount { get; set; }

public decimal MakeWithdraw()
{
    Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to withdraw from your Current account?", WithdrawCurrentAmount);

    if (WithdrawCurrentAmount < 0) 
    {
        throw new Exception("You cannot withdraw a negative amount" );               
    }

    WithdrawCurrentAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    CurrentBalance = CurrentBalance - WithdrawCurrentAmount;
    Console.WriteLine("\nAvailable Current Balance is now: {0}", CurrentBalance);
    return CurrentBalance;     
}
```

Comment: Nice work remembering to use `decimal` for money; many beginners get this wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You must move the `Convert` line to before the if statement, otherwise the value entered by the user isn't set into your test variable

You should also use the [`Decimal.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) method to avoid error when the user enter something like "10 bucks" or anything that can't be converted into a decimal value.

Comment: I just realised about that now, and also thanks for your tip on the Decimal.TryParse. I have not come across this line before, so it is something very useful to know about.

Answer (score 1):

You check the value of `WithdrawCurrentAmount` before assigning the value entered from console - the default value of `decimal` is `0.0` so your `if` condition always returns `false`;

You should assign value before checking:

```
WithdrawCurrentAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine()); // this line now is before checking 

if (WithdrawCurrentAmount < 0) 
{
   throw new Exception("You cannot withdraw a negative amount" );   
}

CurrentBalance = CurrentBalance - WithdrawCurrentAmount;
Console.WriteLine("\nAvailable Current Balance is now: {0}", CurrentBalance);

return CurrentBalance;
```

Also, if you enter something that cannot be converted to `decimal` you will get exception.

Comment: That makes sense now. When I was debugging the If line using a breakpoint, I noticed that it returned the value of 0. A good lesson to learn from that.Thanks for your help.